# RxJS filter() unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rxjs

I came across either this strange behaviour or something I don't know yet.
For the following,

```
of(1).pipe(
  filter(_ => false),
  startWith('hello')
).susbcribe(val => console.log(val));
```

The above code outputs `hello` in the console.

What I expect is since filter will allow only the successful conditions to go down the operator chain, how come it is able to output hello through startWith()? Is it the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startWith` happens **after** you have filtered your contents.

```
of(1).pipe(           // will yield (1)
  filter(_ => false), // will yield ()
  startWith('hello')  // will yield ('hello')
).susbcribe(val => console.log(val));
```

So, the stream that consists of `1`, filtered so as to not let anything pass **is a thing in and of itself**. That thing is then "decorated" with the `startWith` operator, which makes it yield an initial `hello`.

That new stream is the one you subscribe to!

This is indeed intended behaviour.

Let `startWith` be above `filter` in the `pipe(...)` arguments and you'll see how that changes:

```
of(1).pipe(           // will yield (1)
  startWith('hello'), // will yield ('hello', 1)
  filter(_ => false)  // will yield ()
).susbcribe(val => console.log(val));
```

---

To address the concerns in the comments section, you can think of the `pipe` chain as `nested calls`. For instance, in pseudo-code:

```
A.pipe(B, C, D)
```

... is equivalent to doing:

```
D(C(B(A)))
```

Thus, the following:

```
of(1).pipe(           // expression A
  filter(_ => false), // expression B
  startWith('hello')  // expression C
).susbcribe(val => console.log(val));
```

... would translate to:

```
startWith(         // expression C
    filter(        // expression B
        of(1),     // expression A
        _ => false
    ),
    'hello'
).susbcribe(val => console.log(val))
```

Or, in a more "imperative" way:

```
const one = of(1);
const filtered = filter(one, _ => false);
const greeted = startWith(filtered, 'hello');
greeted.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

It then becomes clear that filter can **not** affect the operators further down the chain!

Comment: But shouldn't filter skip the chain of operators that follows, so startWith and all below it should be skipped?

Comment: filter does not ignore operators down the line, it filters values from the observable stream. `startWith` prepends the stream (of filtered values) with the values passed to `startWith`

Comment: @emkay I improved my answer. Don't hesitate to let me know if there still is something bugging you!

Comment: @ccjmne Your explanation in terms of nested calls made it clear. I really forgot, piping operators are just making nested calls.

Answer (score 0):

The [startWith()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/startwith.html) operator just calls the [concat()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html) operator. With the start argument as the first observable and the outer observable as the second.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/40a2209636a8b4d4884f5d59ad206ae458ad2de4/src/internal/operators/startWith.ts#L68

The `concat()` operator emits the values for each observable in sequence from *left* to *right*. The *first* observable must emit all values and complete before the *next* observable is emitted.

For example;

```
   concat(of('a','b'), of('1', '2')
      .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
   // prints 'a', 'b', '1', '2'
```

So we can rewrite your example to use `concat()` instead and generate the same result and this is basically what `startWith()` is doing internally.

```
   concat(of('hello'), of(1).pipe(filter(_ => false))
      .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
   // prints "hello"
```

So `startWith()` *reorders* the sequence of observables so that the *value* is emitted first, but since it is an operator it can only *lift* the outer observable. Any operators placed in `pipe()` *after* `startWith()` will be applied to the observable that is the result of calling `concat()`.